# Is this a pure imaginary number?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, recreational-mathematics, exponentiation

I've met this formula and I need to demonstrate that it is purely imaginary (it has no real part).

$\frac{1}{2}\log(-\exp(i2\pi q))$, //for a real "input" q.

As I don't know much about maths, what I've tried untill now was to prove it by applying Euler's formula, but getting a real cosine there didn't take me to anywhere. 
Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of complex logarithm:
\begin{equation*}
\log(z) = \ln|z| + i \text{arg}(z) = \ln(z) + i \Big( \text{Arg}(z) + 2 \pi \mathbb{Z} \Big)
\end{equation*}
(which in fact is a set of infinite numbers), with $\ln|z|$ the real logarithm of the complex number $z$, and $\text{Arg}(z)$ its principal argument, i.e. the angle $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ when $z$ is written in polar coordinates as $z = r e^{i \theta}$.

For example, taking $z = 2i$, its module is 2, and principal argument $\frac{\pi}{2}$, hence
\begin{equation*}
\log(2i) = \ln(2) + i\Big( \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi \mathbb{Z}\Big)
\end{equation*}

Using this, you can attack now your problem.

Comment: Funny thing about English is "a set of infinite numbers" is extremely different from "an infinite set of numbers." I'm sure the latter is what you meant.